# Is there a way to test environment defined dynamic validations in a model with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, model

I have a model in which some validations are defined dynamically, based on the environment they are are running (trough ENV variables).

For example, I use the `ENV['NETWORK']` variable set to the `'testnet3'` network on development and test, and set to the `'bitcoin'` network on production. Then, let's say I have a model called `Transaction` with a validation set dynamically as follows:

```
Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :output_address,
    presence: output_address_presence_requirement_for ENV['NETWORK'] 
end

# somewhere exists the 'output_address_presence_requirement_for' function

def output_address_presence_requirement_for(network)
  if network == 'testnet3'
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Then, I have two sets of specs: one for the behaviour of the model when using the 'bitcoin' network (production), and one for the behaviour when using the 'testnet3' network (development/test). They work as expected when running each file on its own, but when running one after the other, like on `rspec spec/models`, changing the value of the ENV variable seems to have no effect, and the second set of specs fail.

I've tried using `climate_control`, stubbing of calls to ENV and even setting the value of the ENV variable directly, with the same results on each case: the tests pass if running individually and the second set of tests fail if running them as a whole.

It seems that RSpec reuses the same Rails environment when running a set of tests, and the model validation gets defined when calling the first set of tests but it's not redefined when calling the second one.

I could just use different models with different validations to store the information depending on the used network, but I would like to avoid it as it would require a more complex logic on the controller and more specs.

Is there something that can be done on the RSpec side to make it refresh the environment before it runs a spec file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words:

I would imagine that once you're running the tests altogether, the files are required and the validator is defined ***once***.

Thus the value of the `presence` key remains the same even after you change the value of `ENV['NETWORK']` in the test.

Use a validation method that reads the environment variable each time the object is validated.

Here is an example for the sample code you shared:

```
validate :validator_name

def validator_name
  if (ENV['NETWORK'] != 'testnet3') && output_address.blank?
    # add errors here
  end
end
```

Comment: This approach worked very well stubbing ENV and also using climate_control.